# How to prove this probability problem?

Tags: probability

The question is Suppose that events A and B are that people have diseases a and b, respectively. Suppose that having either disease leads to hospitalization H = A U B. If A and B are believed to be independent events, show that

P{A | BH} < P{A | H}

I think I understand why this holds but do not know how to explain it. I know that P{A|H} is equivalent to P{A} since it's independent from H and I also (think I) know that P{A|BH} is equal to P{AB} and since they are independent this equals P{A}P{B} but now how do I go about proving P{AB} < P{A}? Assuming all the assumptions I've made are correct.

Comment: @RossMillikan sorry about that just fixed it. Yes it's the union

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist, P(A|H)$\neq$ P(A), as A is not independent of H. For example, we can use H and its complement to partition the sample space, then by the theorem of total probability:

P(A) = P($H^{c}$)P(A|$H^{c}$)+P($H$)P(A|$H$),

however, P(A|$H^{c}$)=$0$ therefore, P(A) = P($H$)P(A|$H$), and P(A|$H$) = $\frac{P(A)}{P(H)}$.

So, unless everyone is in the hospital (i.e., P(H)=1), P(A|$H$) $\neq$ P(A).

Your second conclusion is also not correct: P(A|BH) $\neq$ P(AB). Since B $\subset$ H, BH $\rightarrow$ B, so P(A|BH) = P(A|B) = P(A) by assumed independence.

Regarding the above inequality, we can use the above results to show:

P(A|BH) = P(A|B) = P(A) and

P(A|H) = P(AH)/P(H) = P(A)/P(H) (since A $\subset$ H) or

P(A|H)P(H) = P(A) $\rightarrow$ P(A|H)>P(A) = P(A|BH), since P(H)<1.

Comment: I actually got to P(AH)/P(H) But had no idea how yo reduce from there! Your answer is highly appreciated!